# How to generate a list that holds lists of files in a subfolder

Tags: python-3.x

I have a folder(let us call it master foldeR) that has multiple folders(let us call this subfolder). Every subfolder has 5 or fewer PNG files. I wish to store the path of PNG files of every subfolder in a list each. There are multiple subfolders and PNG files from every subfolder need to be in a separate list inside a list. I am only able to store all the paths to PNGs in a single list. Here is my code:

```
import glob
import os.path

image_paths_all = []

for i in range(len(concatenation)):
    image_path = "C:\\Users\\path" + str(i) + "path" + str(i) + "path\\*"
    for file in glob.glob(image_path):
        #print(file)
        image_paths_all.append(file)
```

Suppose my subfolder_1 has 2 PNGS and subfolder_2 has 4 PNGs:

```
C:\\Users\\master_folder\\subfolder_1\\1_1.png
C:\\Users\\master_folder\\subfolder_1\\2_1.png
```

and

```
C:\\Users\\master_folder\\subfolder_2\\1_2.png
C:\\Users\\master_folder\\subfolder_2\\2_2.png
C:\\Users\\master_folder\\subfolder_2\\3_2.png
C:\\Users\\master_folder\\subfolder_2\\4_2.png
```

The code of my output is a list that contains:

```
C:\\Users\\master_folder\\subfolder_1\\1_1.png
C:\\Users\\master_folder\\subfolder_1\\2_1.png
C:\\Users\\master_folder\\subfolder_2\\1_2.png
C:\\Users\\master_folder\\subfolder_2\\2_2.png
C:\\Users\\master_folder\\subfolder_2\\3_2.png
C:\\Users\\master_folder\\subfolder_2\\4_2.png
```

My **expected output** is a list (call master list) that contains:
`[C:\\Users\\master_folder\\subfolder_1\\1_1.png,C:\\Users\\master_folder\\subfolder_1\\2_1.png]` as one list inside master list **and**

`[C:\\Users\\master_folder\\subfolder_2\\1_2.png,C:\\Users\\master_folder\\subfolder_2\\2_2.png,C:\\Users\\master_folder\\subfolder_2\\3_2.png,C:\\Users\\master_folder\\subfolder_2\\4_2.png]` as another list inside master list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this example. 
My directory structure:

```
test
├── sub1
│   ├── 1_2.png
│   └── 1.png
└── sub2
    ├── 1_3.png
    └── out.png
```

code:

```
import os

sub_folders_path = 'test'    
image_paths_all = []

for sub_folder in os.listdir(sub_folders_path):

    path = os.path.join(sub_folders_path, sub_folder)

    files = os.listdir(path)
    files_path = [os.path.join(path, file) for file in files]

    image_paths_all.append(files_path)
```

output:

```
[['1_3.png', 'out.png'], ['1_2.png', '1.png']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it:

```
master_list = [[] for i in range(len(dataframe))]

for i in range(len(dataframe)):
    image_path = "C:\\Users\\path" + str(i) + "path\\" + str(i) + "path\\*"
    for file in glob.glob(image_path):
        master_list[i].append(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really easy with os.walk. Here is a working code, comment if you have some bugs or need clarification.

```
import os

tex=0
b = []
lod = [[],[]]

root = 'C:/Users/master_folder'

a=os.listdir(root)
for i in a:
    b.append(os.listdir(root+i))

for x in b:
    for lx in x:
        lod[tex].append(os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, lx)))
    tex+=1

print(lod)
```